# Общее обстоятельство в сложноподчиненном

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Предложение: В этом году весна задержалась и с наступлением благоприятной погоды на посевной мы полностью используем весь световой день.
Можно ли считать "в этом году" общим обстоятельством и нужно ли ставить запятую перед "и"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***В этом году весна задержалась, и с наступлением благоприятной погоды на посевной мы используем весь световой день.***

Обстоятельство "в этом году" относится к первой части предложения, запятая нужна. Вторая часть, в отличие от первой,  имеет дополнительное значение следствиия. Ср.:*В этом году весна задержалась, так что с наступлением благоприятной погоды на посевной мы используем весь световой день.*

Слово "полностью" лучше убрать, так как Вы используете местоимение ВЕСЬ.